# JPA - Select a field with a calculation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, postgis

Basically I am trying to select a field where I calculate with using a Postgres postgis query ST_distance_sphere.

Below code allows me to filter out results based on the distance. If the distance is greater than the given value record is filtered. I created the following query with the below predicate builder. However I also want to select the distance value returned by the ST_distance_sphere function as "distance"

Here is how I use JPQL:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<RestaurantEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(RestaurantEntity.class).distinct(true);

    Root<RestaurantEntity> restaurantEntityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(RestaurantEntity.class);
    Predicate[] searchPredicates = createPredicates(criteriaBuilder, restaurantEntityRoot, restaurantSearch);
    List<Order> orders = getSortingOrders(restaurantSearch, criteriaBuilder, restaurantEntityRoot);

    criteriaQuery.where(searchPredicates).orderBy(orders);

    List<RestaurantEntity> searchResults = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
            .setMaxResults(restaurantSearch.getSize())
            .setFirstResult((restaurantSearch.getPage()) * restaurantSearch.getSize())
            .getResultList();
```

Here is searchByDistance function and JpaRestaurantPredicateBuilder class I use.

```
class JpaRestaurantPredicateBuilder {
        private CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
        private Root<RestaurantEntity> restaurantEntityRoot;
        private List<Predicate> predicateList;
        JpaRestaurantPredicateBuilder(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<RestaurantEntity> restaurantEntityRoot) {
            this.criteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilder;
            this.restaurantEntityRoot = restaurantEntityRoot;
            this.predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        JpaRestaurantPredicateBuilder searchByDistance(Float lon, Float lat, Long maxDistance) {
            Point userLocation = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(lon, lat));
            Join address = this.restaurantEntityRoot.join("addressEntity", JoinType.INNER);
            predicateList.add(new WithinDistancePredicate((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder, address.get("location"), userLocation,  maxDistance));
            return this;
        }

        Predicate[] buildArray() {
            return predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]);
        }
    }
```

Here is createPredicates:

```
    private Predicate[] createPredicates(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<RestaurantEntity> restaurantEntityRoot, RestaurantSearch restaurantSearch) {
            return new JpaRestaurantPredicateBuilder(criteriaBuilder, restaurantEntityRoot)
                    .chainId(restaurantSearch.getChainId())
                    .searchTerm(retrieveRestaurantIdsForSearchTerm(restaurantSearch.getSearchTerm()))
                    .cityIdAndDistrictId(restaurantSearch.getCityId(), restaurantSearch.getDistrictId())
                    .status(restaurantSearch.getStatus())
                    .searchByDistance(restaurantSearch.getLon(), restaurantSearch.getLat(), restaurantSearch.getMaxDistance())
                    .buildArray();
        }
```

And here is the generated sql:

```
    select distinct restaurant0_.id
    from restaurant restaurant0_
       inner join address addressent1_ on restaurant0_.address_id = addressent1_.id
    where st_distance_sphere(addressent1_.location, ?) < 1000
    order by restaurant0_.id desc
    limit ?
```

Here is the sql I want to generate using JPA **(note the line where I select the distance)**:

```
    select distinct restaurant0_.id,
    st_distance_sphere(addressent1_.location, ?) as distance
    from restaurant restaurant0_
       inner join address addressent1_ on restaurant0_.address_id = addressent1_.id
    where st_distance_sphere(addressent1_.location, ?) < 1000
    order by restaurant0_.id desc
    limit ?
```

I couldn't find any other answers related with this question. How can I achieve this query using JPA? I tried to use CriteriaQuery's select method to no avail.

Comment: Since you don't post your use of JPQL or Criteria then what do you expect people to say. All of those method calls are presumably your code.

Comment: Edited as per @BillyFrost comments

Comment: right, and where is the `CriteriaQuery.select` or `CriteriaQuery.multiselect` call?

Comment: @BillyFrost not currently in the code as `entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
            .setMaxResults(restaurantSearch.getSize())
            .setFirstResult((restaurantSearch.getPage()) * restaurantSearch.getSize())
            .getResultList();` returns the list of entities. Which does not contain the calculated distance field. Which is part of my question :)

Comment: so call `criteriaQuery.multiselect` with the id and the calculated Predicate then